# Python - PyQt5 - como inserir um QGridLayout dentro de um QMainWindow?

Tags: python

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou com um problema.

Estou utilizando o QMainWindow para criar uma tela onde eu insiro um QMenuBar com sucesso, mas ai vou tentar inserir um QGridLayout e não dá certo. Não aparece erro mas também não mostra os componentes teoricamente ligados a ele.

O Código é o seguinte abaixo:

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QAction, QWidget

__version__ = "1.0.0"

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'System Converter Database - Version: '
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 400
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title + __version__)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - self.rect().center())

        # Adicionando os componentes
        # Menu principal
        main_menu = self.menuBar()
        menu_scd = main_menu.addMenu("SCD")
        menu_scd.addAction("Criar SCD")
        menu_scd.addAction("Localizar SCD")
        main_menu.addSeparator()

        # Menu Conversor
        menu_converter = main_menu.addMenu("Conversor")
        menu_converter_passo = menu_converter.addMenu("Passo-a-passo")
        menu_converter_passo.addAction("Copiar")
        menu_converter_passo.addAction("Extrair")
        menu_converter_passo.addAction("Preparar")
        menu_converter_passo.addAction("Converter")
        menu_converter_automatico = menu_converter.addMenu("Automático")
        menu_converter_automatico.addAction("Iniciar")

        # Menu Verificador
        menu_verificador = main_menu.addMenu("Verificador")
        menu_verificador.addAction("Iniciar")

        # Menu Sair
        menu_quit = QAction("Sair", self)
        menu_quit.triggered.connect(self.sair)
        main_menu.addAction(menu_quit)

        # Grade principal

        title = QLabel('Title')
        titleEdit = QLineEdit()

        grid_main = QGridLayout()
        grid_main.setSpacing(5)

        grid_main = QGridLayout()
        grid_main.addWidget(title, 1, 0)
        grid_main.addWidget(titleEdit, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(grid_main)


        self.show()

    def sair(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defina o layout em um QWidget simples e configure-o como um widget central da janela principal.

```
QWidget* widget = new QWidget(mainWindow);
widget->setLayout(gridLayout);
mainWindow->setCentralWidget(widget);
```

Se no console aparecer a seguinte mensagem:

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QMainWindow "", which already has a layout
```

É porque você passou a janela principal como pai para o QGridLayout. Isso significa o mesmo que definir o layout na janela principal. Portanto, não passe nenhum pai ou passe o widget central como pai para o layout da grade.

Comment: Bom dia Réulison Silva.
Esse código utilizado é novo para mim. O modo como foi especificado as variáveis(se pode chamar assim).
Por que conheço normalmente assim:

nome_variavel = metodo()

Poderia fazer a gentileza de me esclarecer?

Grato.

Comment: Realmente não consegui implementar o que você propôs.  Até pesquisei e mostra a mesma sugestão, ,as mão sei como implementar isso no meu código. Preciso de ajuda, por gentileza.

Comment: Se eu coloco exatamente o que foi mencionado (isso porque não sei como isso se aplica ao python, pois iniciante ainda) acontece o seguinte erro:

QWidget* widget = new QWidget()
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Consegui resolver assim:

        # Grade principal
        main_grid = QGridLayout(self)
        qwidget = QWidget()
        qwidget.setLayout(main_grid)
        self.setCentralWidget(qwidget)



        # Adicionando widgets
        title = QLabel('Title')
        titleEdit = QLineEdit()

        main_grid.addWidget(title, 1, 0)
        main_grid.addWidget(titleEdit, 1, 1)

Claro que isso é o que foi dito acima. Mas como colocar outra QGrid dentro dessa que acabei de criar?

Comment: O que você pode fazer é criar um QWidget configurado como o widget central (mainWindow) e atribuir a este um layout. QMainWindow tem seu próprio layout para colocar statusbar e mainmenu, assim você não pode definir um outro diretamente.